# Extract multiple columns and add null character in between

Tags: awk, sed, fasta

I have a file with the following format :

```
TRINITY_DN119001_c0_g1_i1   4   *   0   0   *   *   0   0   GAGCCTCCCTCATGAATGTACCAGCATTTACCTCATAAAGAGCT    *   XO:Z:NM 
TRINITY_DN119037_c0_g1_i1   4   *   0   0   *   *   0   0   TAAGATTAGGTTGTATTCCAG   *   XO:Z:NM 
TRINITY_DN119099_c0_g1_i1   4   *   0   0   *   *   0   0   AGGCAGGCGCTAAACGATTTGCATTTCTCTAATGATTACGCCAG    *   XO:Z:NM
```

I am trying to extract the 1st and 10th column and store it in the following format(output file) :

```
>TRINITY_DN119099_c0_g1_i1  
GAGCCTCCCTCATGAATGTACCAGCATTTACCTCATAAAGAGCT    
>TRINITY_DN119037_c0_g1_i1
TAAGATTAGGTTGTATTCCAG
>TRINITY_DN119001_c0_g1_i1  
AGGCAGGCGCTAAACGATTTGCATTTCTCTAATGATTACGCCAG
```

I am doing the following code for now :

```
cut -d "  " -f1,10 in.txt > out.txt
sed 's/^/>/' out.txt
```

but,unable to get how to get above output.

Comment: `TAAGATTAGG` nightmare...

Comment: lol @GillesQuenot

Comment: @oguzismail Get the format like one in output.

Comment: @shome is this a tab delimited file?

Comment: Aka `DNA` nightmare. Poorly written usually

Comment: `cut -f1,10 in.txt | sed 's/^/>/;s/\t/\n/'`should work then

Comment: You mean 1st and 10th columns, not 1st and 9th, right?

Comment: What does this have to do with adding a null character somewhere, btw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `awk`:

```
awk '{printf ">%s\n%s\n", $1, $10}' file
```

```
>TRINITY_DN119001_c0_g1_i1
GAGCCTCCCTCATGAATGTACCAGCATTTACCTCATAAAGAGCT
>TRINITY_DN119037_c0_g1_i1
TAAGATTAGGTTGTATTCCAG
>TRINITY_DN119099_c0_g1_i1
AGGCAGGCGCTAAACGATTTGCATTTCTCTAATGATTACGCCAG
```

However note that it is 1st and 10th column in your shown output instead of 9th.

Answer (score 0):

if your data in 'd' file, try gnu sed:

```
 sed -E 's/^(TRINITY_DN\S+).*\s([ACGT]+).*/\1\n\2/' d
```